# Why does Postgraphile's <X>Connection type allow NULLs in its nodes list?

Tags: graphql, postgraphql

If I have table `X`, why does the Postgraphile-generated schema for `XConnection` allow nulls in the returned list?

`type XConnection { nodes: [X]! }`

instead of

`type XConnection { nodes: [X!]! }`

I could not come up with examples where either the `allXs` query or any 1-N relation to `X` would have a meaningful use of `null` in the list. This  translates into an `Option` or `Maybe` type in a typed language which makes navigation cumbersome, so I'm wondering when it would be `null`.

And why does `allXs` return an `XConnection` (allowing a null list) instead of `XConnection!`? Would a `null` here mean the same as empty `[]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `create function x() returns setof my_table ...` functions can return nulls as well as table rows. In my opinion, doing so is a bad practice. If you agree, and can commit to not doing so, then you can use the "no SETOF functions contain nulls" flag to add the missing not null you asked about.

```
-N, --no-setof-functions-contain-nulls
if none of your RETURNS SETOF compound_type functions mix NULLs with the results 
then you may enable this to reduce the nullables in the GraphQL schema
```

(I'm the PostGraphile maintainer, and added this option.)

As for the root level field `allXs`; it's good practice in a GraphQL schema for all root level fields to be nullable because if they are not and one root level field fails (e.g. SQL query failed, or DB is not available right now) then the *entire GraphQL result* will be null, rather than just the field that failed. GraphQL is big on limiting failures to small areas, hence the "nullable by default" approach.

Comment: I've written up more in-depth explanation of why the various parts of a PostGraphile schema are nullable here: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/why-nullable/ (including tips to make parts non-nullable)